# Count total number of records based on answers

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a result which displays two answers and i want to result the total number of counts by each record. With my query i display two answers (like and dislike). i want to count the total number of like and also the total number of dislike

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN  log_time <= rdate_up THEN 'like' ELSE 'dislike' end )as answer
FROM dbo.users
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Try providing some example data and the result you want to see from it

Comment: Yeah I'm not exactly sure I follow what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the `algorithm` you gave us to validate if value is a `like` or `dislike` is

```
log_time <= rdate_up
```

Then you could use `union` and `count` to separate them.

```
select count(*) as count_of_like
from dbo.users
where log_time <= rdate_up
union
select count(*) as count_of_dislike
from dbo.users
where log.time > rdate_up;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this another way using CASE. This will be faster because it only hits the base table once.

```
select sum(case when log_time <= rdate_up then 1 end) as LikeCount
    , SUM(case when log.time > rdate_up then 1 end) as DislikeCount
from dbo.users
```